# Webpack jstz_min not defined

Tags: javascript, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I am using webpack  with the following code

```
var webpack = require("webpack");    
module.exports = [
{
  name: 'libs',
  entry: [   
      'js/jstz.js',
      'js/jstz_min.js'
    ],
  output:{
        filename: "libs.js"
    },  
  resolve: {
      alias: {
        jstz_min: 'jstz_min.js'
      }
  }
},    
{
  name: 'main',
  entry:  [
       'jstzDemo.js'
      ],
  output: {
    filename: "main.js"
  }
}];
```

In jstzDemo.js I am having the following code

```
 function getTimezoneName() {
        timezone = jstz_min.determine()
        return timezone.name();
    }
```

In index.html I included libs.js and main.js which are output files from webpack

I downloaded jstz_min from [jstz_min](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/Jstz-104minjs)

Issue is on loading of the page, "ReferenceError: jstz_min is not defined" error is occuring.Any changes needed in the webpack.config.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested, but your config can be changed to this:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");    
module.exports = [
{
  entry: {
      main: 'jstzDemo.js',
      libs: 'js/jstz_min.js'
  },
  output:{
      filename: "[name].js"
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('libs', 'libs.js')
  ]
}];
```

jstzDemo.js:

```
var jstz = require('js/jstz_min.js');

function getTimezoneName() {
    timezone = jstz.determine()
    return timezone.name();
}
```

Comment: I have var abc = {} in a.js and I am using method of abc ie., abc.methodName = {} in b.js..output.js is the webpack generated file which generated on running webpack..when I am using output.js it is showing abc undefined.Any way to handle this kind of global variables in webpack config?

Comment: It can be done with `expose-loader` ( https://github.com/webpack/expose-loader ): `require('expose?abc!a.js')`. But ES6 modules works in other way: https://spring.io/understanding/javascript-modules